# Centos 6 ISO with custom kernel

Tags: centos, kernel, iso

I need to build a Centos ISO with a 3.2 Kernel to setup a new server, how I can do this?

The server has a Raid Controller that's not supported in previous Kernel Versions, which means I can not install Centos 6.3 and change later the Kernel as the HDD are not showed.

Comment: I tried to load the driver on install, which works but on every kernel update (it's problematic on this two server to disable updates) it don't load anymore. Then I had the idea to install Centos 6.3 with a Kernel 3.2 who has builtin support for it.

Comment: Now that Oracle Linux is free, have you tried that? Oracle Linux 6.3 has a current kernel of 2.6.39. I switched away from CentOS almost immediately when it became available.

Comment: @Michael Hampton I don't know that Oracle Linux has a newer Kernel then Redhat/Centos, I'm actually downloading it and probably that will solve my problem. Thank you!

Comment: In Oracle Linux 6, it's the `kernel-uek` package.

Answer (score 1):

Check with the RAID card manufacturer to see if they have a driver disk available for RHEL/CentOS installations. There is a [driver disk functionality](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/chap-Updating_drivers_during_installation_on_Intel_and_AMD_systems.html) in the RH installer that allows modules for unsupported hardware to be inserted at install time.

Sometimes the manufacturer of the server provides the enhanced driver.

Are you even sure that this RAID controller is supported by CentOS in general?

Can you provide the server manufacturer and RAID card model?

Comment: Yes it is supported, I have injected a driver on install, after every kernel update it don't load and it cost much time to handle them. It's a Adaptec 6805E. http://ask.adaptec.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/17181

Comment: The above DKMS way I didn't tested, as I'm not really sure on it. I don't want again some half day tasks to bring the server up.